# Geometry and Equation centering: strange behavior

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, amsmath, geometry

I have found a strange "bug", where my equations do not seem to be aligned correctly when using the `geometry` package. I try to explain this behavior in more detail using this MWE:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, 12pt ]{book}

\RequirePackage[]{geometry}    % works, when this line is deleted
\RequirePackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%\section{TEST}    % does work
\chapter{TEST}     % does not work

This is an equation
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}(t) =  \frac{ a b c d e f }{\pi} \operatorname{lim} \left[ \mathcal{X}_a[\boldsymbol{\mu}(t)](a+b) + \mathcal{X}_a[\boldsymbol{\mu}(t)](a+b) + d e f \right].
\end{align}
And this is an equation
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{B}(t) =\frac{a}{\pi} \operatorname{lim} \left[ \frac{ \mathcal{X}_a[\boldsymbol{\mu}(t)](a+b) + \boldsymbol{\mu}(0) }{a + b} + \frac{ \mathcal{X}_a[\boldsymbol{\mu}(t)](a+b) + \boldsymbol{\mu}(0) }{a - b} \right].
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, two (meaningless) equations are shown below each other in this very simple document. Strangely, when compiled, **the second equation is not aligned to the center, but is clearly shifted to the left.** Its horizontal alignment is broken.

Even more strangely, this bug does only occur, if I use a `\chapter`, but not, if I use a `\section` in the beginning. Furthermore, it seems to be tied to the `geometry` package. When this package is turned off, the alignment works again. It is also worth to mention that only *some* equations seem to be off the center - most certainly depending on certain characters (probably `amsmath` symbols) which they contain.

I have absolutely no idea whats going on although I really tried a lot to solve this. **Can you please help me to get my equations aligned properly?**

Remark: I was able to reproduce this bug on different systems.

Comment: When an equation is “too near” to the equation number, it is shifted left; the amount of shifting is so that “space before+equation+space after+equation number = line width”, with equal spaces before and after. This is “by design”, so not a bug at all.

Comment: Are you sure? So why does it depend on `geometry` and `\chapter`?

Comment: Using `geometry` changes the line width; with no `\chapter`, the equation number doesn't have a prefix, while its size increases when `\chapter` is issued.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I was not aware of that centering constraint and I think it does not look good. Can you give me a hint how these limits can be configured?

Comment: They're built in TeX (at least for `equation`, which uses the primitive setting); the `amsmath` environments do no different. The treshold is exactly the width of the equation number; if the space between the centered equation is less than this width, the centering is done in the available space (line width minus width of equation number); `amsmath` just adds that, if no space remains, the equation number is shifted down.

Comment: Alright. If you write a brief answer to this question, I will accept it. Otherwise, I will hand in an answer on my own later. In any case, I would still be interested in a straightforward way how to access these spacing parameters, since they can in some cases lead to visually very unappealing results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you see is not a bug, but a consequence of how TeX has been written.

Let's examine the case of `equation`, which is also followed by the `amsmath` environments that just add the shifting down of the equation number in case the equation is overlong.

The rules are not really straightforward, but basically they are as follows (it's a simplified version, but not far from the truth).

1. Measure the horizontal size available for the equation (usually the line width), *d*
2. Measure the width of the equation, *w*
3. Measure the size of the equation number, *e*
4. Try centering the equation, which would leave a space (*d* – *w*)/2 on either side
5. If (*d* – *w*)/2 – *e* < *e*, center the equation in the available space *d* – *e*

These rules are built in and there's no way of changing them, besides using a hand-made alignment.

The tentatively centered equation is considered too near to the equation number (case 5) if the space between the equation and the equation number is less than the width of the equation number itself, in order to keep a good visual distinction.

Your cases show different results for several reasons

1. `\usepackage{geometry}` changes the standard line width of the `book` class
2. If no `\chapter` command is issued, the equation number has no prefix
3. When `\chapter` is issued, the first equation number becomes (1.1), which is wider than (1), so triggering step 5 countermeasure.

You may not like it, but that's what TeX does. The inequality evaluated in step 5 is hardwired and there's no way to change them (except by rewriting TeX).

The full description can be found on pages 188–189 of the TeXbook.